# Why page speed not combining js & css in one line and why its combining in different groups?

Tags: pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I have site in word press i have installed mod page on my aws server.

i have used combine_css,combine_javascript filter but it not combining js and css in one line its combining  in different different groups.

So i want combine my js,css file in one line for 2 different  files like js and css.

I have tried bellow setting in `/pagespeed.conf` file.but it's not working

My page speed setting :-

```
ModPagespeedRewriteLevel PassThrough

ModPagespeedEnableFilters add_head,combine_css,combine_javascript,convert_meta_tags,extend_cache,fallback_rewrite_css_urls,flatten_css_imports,inline_css, inline_import_to_link,
inline_javascript,rewrite_css,rewrite_images,rewrite_javascript,rewrite_style_attributes_with_url

 ModPagespeedFileCacheSizeKb          102400
 ModPagespeedFileCacheCleanIntervalMs 3600000
 ModPagespeedLRUCacheKbPerProcess     1024
 ModPagespeedLRUCacheByteLimit        16384
 ModPagespeedCssFlattenMaxBytes       2048
 ModPagespeedCssInlineMaxBytes        2048
 ModPagespeedCssImageInlineMaxBytes   0
 ModPagespeedImageInlineMaxBytes      3072
 ModPagespeedJsInlineMaxBytes         2048
 ModPagespeedCssOutlineMinBytes       3000
 ModPagespeedJsOutlineMinBytes        3000
 ModPagespeedMaxCombinedCssBytes      -1
 ModPagespeedMaxCombinedJsBytes       92160

  ModPagespeedCombineAcrossPaths off
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have a recent version of mod_pagespeed installed, viewing the html source for a page that displays the problem with ?PageSpeedFilters=+debug appended to the querystring should help. The debug filter should write a comment about why combining failed.

I wrote a short piece about that:
http://blog.iispeed.com/2015/04/debugging-page-speed-debug-filter.html